# Elasticsearch file-based index templates not showing up in "/_template" API call

Tags: elasticsearch, chef-infra, elasticsearch-indices

I'm attempting to automate the usage of index templates in Elasticsearch, so I've started creating the files in the "[ES_CONFIG_DIR]/templates/" directory (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html#config) with the proper format (sample file: http://pastebin.com/waKCBGgW).  My Chef cookbook performs the following steps:

1.Create the JSON template file in the "[ES_CONFIG_DIR]/templates/tpl_misc.json" directory
2.Restart the elasticsearch service

The block of chef code to complete this is:

Related Attributes:

```
    default['elasticsearch']['index_templates'] = [
      "tpl_misc"
    ]
```

Relate Recipe Code:

```
    directory "#{node['elasticsearch']['path']['conf']}/templates" do
     owner 'elasticsearch'
     group 'elasticsearch'
     mode '0755'
     action :create
    end

    node['elasticsearch']['index_templates'].each do |tpl|
      template "#{node['elasticsearch']['path']['conf']}/templates/#{tpl}.json" do
        source "#{tpl}.erb"
        owner 'elasticsearch'
        group 'elasticsearch'
        mode '0644'
        notifies :restart, 'service[elasticsearch]'
      end
    end
```

I can confirm the template files are being created where they should (in /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/templates) although when I check to see exists in ES (curl -iL http://localhost:9200/_template/tpl_misc) and i always get a 404.  Does anyone have any advice on what my issue might be?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: a permission error ? (with cookbook code it may help understand what's going wrong)

Comment: It's not a permission error.  If I go on that server and manually issue the equivalent curl call I get the 404 error, which is because the template does not exist:

`$ curl -iL http://localhost:9200/_template/tpl_misc`
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2
{}`

Comment: I mean a permission error on the  `tpl_misc.json`  file. If elasticsearch does not own it, maybe it does not load it at startup (or even it can't read it). what does say the elasticsearch log at startup ? And again, what is your chef code (edit your question to add it, comments are not good to format code)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that.  The **templates/** directory and the files in it are owned by "elasticsearch".  I've updated my questions to show the related chef code.

Comment: I see no reason for it not to work, is your json file valid (pastebin si blocked here, I can't verify). Does elasticsearch say something at startup in its logs about it ? (can't load, any stacktrace about parsing the template ?)

Answer (score 1):

I've learned that index templates added as files in the "[CONFIG]/templates/" directory do not currently appear in the results of the *"/_template/*"* API method.  Someone refers to that in the following email thread:

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Loading-of-index-settings-template-from-file-in-config-templates-td4024923.html#d1366317284000-941

Although it was not documented in the [official index templates](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) documentation on the Elasticsearch website.  I've since then created a [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10160) to have the documentation updated which has also lead to an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10193) being opened in order to have ability added to the "/_template/" API method.

Answer (score 0):

Templates from config files are no longer supported. Use a PUT request to the api instead.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/breaking_20_index_api_changes.html#_file_based_index_templates

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10193

This can be automated using curl for those trying to use ansible or something to provision their nodes. The main drawback being that you have to wait for your node to be up before you can curl.